# Java how to import java.util.Random into created package?

Tags: java, package

I decided to created a new package and I made a class inside that package and tried to `import java.util.Random` and it gives me an error "syntax error on token "package", . Expected.

Typing `import java.util.Random` worked in the default package.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: import java.util.Random;                                                                         package ballhockeymanagergame;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
 
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `package` should come before the `import`

```
package ballhockeymanagergame;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main { public static void main(String[] args) { } }
```